# Scikit-Learn with Dask-Distributed using nested parallelism?

Tags: parallel-processing, scikit-learn, data-science, dask, joblib

For example suppose I have the code:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input=u'filename', decode_error=u'replace')
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())
pipeline = Pipeline([
('vect', vectorizer),
('clf', classifier)])

 with parallel_backend('distributed',    scheduler_host=host_port):
    scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=10)
```

If I execute this code I can see in the dask webview (through Bokeh) that 10 tasks are created (1 for each fold). However if I execute:

(I know X and y should be split into training and testing, but this is just for testing purposes).

```
with parallel_backend('distributed', scheduler_host=host_port):
    pipeline.fit(X,y)
```

I can see 1 task for each y class being created (20 in my case). Is there a way to have the cross_val_score be run in parallel AND the underlying OneVsRestClassifier run in parallel? Or is the original code of

```
with parallel_backend('distributed', scheduler_host=host_port):
    scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=10)
```

running the OneVsRestClassifier in parallel along with the cross_val_score in parallel and I'm just not seeing it? Will I have to implement this manually with dask-distributed?

Answer (score 0):

The design of the parallel backends of joblib is currently too limited to handle nested parallel calls. This problem is tracked here: https://github.com/joblib/joblib/pull/538

We will also need to extend the distributed backend of joblib to use http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.get_client